# JavaScript/React sort by variable JSON key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

Given an array;

```
const myArray = [
        {
            name : "Tom",
            age : 28,
            eyes : "brown"
        },
        {
            name : "Dave",
            age : 45,
            eyes : "green"
        },
        {
            name : "Harry",
            age : 22,
            eyes : "green"
        },
    ];
```

I know of the simple way to sort an array with the ternary operator

```
.sort((a, b) => a.age < b.age ? 1 : -1)
```

but I'm looking to make that age a variable key that I toggle with React useState so it would be more like;

```
.sort((a, b) => a.toggle < b.toggle ? 1 : -1);

const [toggle, setToggle] = useState('name');
```

But obviously putting the string 'name' in there won't work and just having name without quote marks returns that the variable does not exist. I've been racking my brain with how to say to JavaScript "use the JSON key, name, or age", not the string or a variable called name/age. Any help on this greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is `toggle`? btw, only to values for sorting irritates the algorithm.

Comment: @AndrewLi I interpret as OP wants to change the key to sort. Not inital value is `"name"`

Comment: You need to use bracket notation like this: `a[toggle]`. Also, you need to return `0` from compareFunction when the values are same.

Comment: @charlietfl Ahhh, so the key itself is changing. If that's the case then this likely dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896

Comment: @AndrewLi Ah yes, you are right. What's the process now? Do I delete the post or leave it up? I also want to make sure Nina and Dickens get the SO points they deserve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `useState` is a function and let us say `key` is the variable for the
function definition

Then `a[key]` will assume `a.name` in your case

if you pass "age" the `a[key]` will assume `a.age` in your case.

With your example, you may do something like this:

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState('name');
const sortedList = myArray.sort((a, b) => a[toggle] < b[toggle] ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: useState is a ReactJS function, sorry I should have been a bit clearer with that

Answer (score 3):

You could hand over a variable for the property.

```
const sortBy = k => (a, b) => a[k] > b[k] || -(a[k] < b[k]);

array.sort(sortBy('age'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` notation for variable object keys and check the type of the values to determine the sort comparison to use

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState('name');

const sortedList = myArray.sort((a, b) => {
   const aVal = a[toggle],
         bVal = b[toggle];
    
    if(typeof aVal === 'number'){
       return aVal - bVal;
    }
    return aVal.localeCompare(bVal)
});
```